# "Interested with the course" or "interested in the course"?

Tags: prepositions

> Interested ***in/with*** the course

Which preposition is correct? *in* or *with,* or both.

Answer (score 1):

"interested" is always followed with "in" in the sense of wanting/desiring to learn about or get involved with something.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interested

(Collins COBUILD English Usage, note 1)

Comment: Hmmm.... _always_ is such a [strong](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22interested+with+*%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&start=200) word (although I'll freely point out that _in_ is indeed [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interested+in+the%2C(interested+with+the+*+40)&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)).

Comment: @J.R. I was paraphrasing what Collins said. I may change the word later.