# Differences of 'with' and 'in'

Tags: prepositions, difference

With- used to say that people or things are in a place together or are doing something together.

In- used as a function word to indicate inclusion, location, or position within limits.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: is "Im interested in you" and "I'm interested with you" possible?

Comment: are they the same when In say "I'm interested in you" and "I'm interested with you"?

Comment: _Interested with_ is not a normal construction. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77922/interested-with-the-course-or-interested-in-the-course